# Centering a QDialog relative to its parent while using RestoreGeometry()

Tags: qt

I have a program that has several QDialogs. Most are a fixed size, but one is a resizable editor. The editor dialog gets its geometry restored from a QByteArray.

The problem I'm having is the Editor is **not** being centered correctly. (only the window's x/y dimensions) The Editor usually appears in the upper left corner when it is instantiated.

The Editor class gets instantiated like this in MainWindow:

```
Editor e(this);
e.exec();
```

For some reason, restoring the window geometry breaks the Editor's automatic centering relative to its parent. Before I implemented the SaveGeometry and RestoreGeomentry code today, the editor worked fine.

Here's the SaveGeometry code in Editor.cpp: (it gets executed right before the current Editor object is destroyed)

```
// Remember current window size
QByteArray geo=saveGeometry();
SettingsManager s;
s.SaveEditorSize(geo);
```

Here's the restore code in Editor.cpp: (this is part of a function that sets up the UI, assigns a layout, etc.)

```
if(!Buffer::editor_geometry.isEmpty()){
    restoreGeometry(Buffer::editor_geometry);
}
```

Does anyone know what the problem is?

Edit: Actually, it does remember where it was last time, it just won't center.

Comment: The "geometry" of a window includes its position (relative) to the parent and its size. If you restore saved geometry then it is going to reappear at whatever position it was saved with.

Comment: To me, the x/y size in the saved geometry is more important than the window position. Is there a way to override the saved position while preserving size? Alternatively how could I calculate the correct centered position based on the current coordinates/size of the MainWindow?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I think I've solved this.

Instead of storing the entire window geometry, I tried storing just the size as a QSize. The size is then reapplied through QDialog::Resize() when the Editor is initialized. The window remembers its previous size *and* remains centered to parent like it is supposed to.